# How to set up a route to serve reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, go, gorilla, mux

I'm trying to set up a route to serve my reactjs application.

I have my index.html and bundle.js in the public folder

```
/public/index.html
/public/bundle.js
```

I'm using go as my backend API, and also to serve my reactjs app.

I created a subroute for my app like:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

app := r.Host("app.example.com").Subrouter()
```

So any request with app as the subdomain will be for my Reactjs app.

So now I have to serve every request regardless of the URL to my reactjs app.

Is path prefix what I need here?

I tried this:

```
app.PathPrefix("/").Handler(serveReact)

func serveReact(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
}
```

But I get this error:

> cannot use serveReact (type func() http.Handler) as type http.Handler
>   in argument to app.PathPrefix("/").Handler:   func() http.Handler does
>   not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your http handler needs a `ServeHTTP` method. If you pass your function to `http.HandlerFunc`, that will be introduced for you:

```
app.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.HandlerFunc(serveReact))

func serveReact(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
}
```

> The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a Handler that calls f.

[source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go)

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

Similarly, you could use the mux router `HandlerFunc` instead:

```
app.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(serveReact)

func serveReact(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
}
```

This essentially performs both steps for you in a combined single step.

Comment: My other routes work with r.HanddleFunc, why does PathPrefix want something so different?

Comment: Well you are using the `Handler` method. Maybe you were using the `HandlerFunc` method in the other cases? https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/077b44c2cf82958550c79f5885ee64900cdcee22/route.go#L118-L123 vs https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/077b44c2cf82958550c79f5885ee64900cdcee22/route.go#L125-L128

I'm updating my answer to show how you could avoid having to wrap it in the `http.HandlerFunc()`.